# Queueing WCF calls from silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, asynchronous, queue

In my Silverlight usercontrol I am listening to events from the application and calls a WCF service to do some action

```
void SelectedCustomerEvent(string customer)
{
//.......

_wcfserviceagent.GetCustomer(customer, callback);
}

  void callback(ObservableCollection<CustomerType> customer)
{

//do some action

}
```

In certain scenarios the event gets fired more than once when doing certain actions. The trouble is the callback is not necessarily called in the order of calls to the WCF service.

Is there anyway to make sure the calls and callback are always called in order?

Ideally, I want the the execution in such a way that for an event it will call the service and callback, and any other calls come in between will get queued. Of course, I can't block the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to ensure the sequence of calls to the WCF service is to implement your own queue on the client.

For example:

```
Queue<string> _customersQueue = new Queue<string>();
bool _fetching;
void SelectedCustomerEvent(string customer)
{
    _customersQueue.Enqueue(customer);
    //.......
    if (!_fetching)
    {
        DoFetchCustomer(_customersQueue.Dequeue());
    }
}

void DoFetchCustomer(string customer)
{
    _fetching = true;
    _wcfserviceagent.GetCustomer(customer, callback);
}

void callback(ObservableCollection<CustomerType> customer)
{
    _fetching = false;
    //do some action
    if (_customersQueue.Count > 0)
    {
        DoFetchCustomer(_customersQueue.Dequeue());
    }
}
```